# How to not repeat an else statement

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
public class array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names[] = {"John", "Mary", "Peter"};

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String nameEntered = myScanner.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i <= names.length; i++) {
            if (nameEntered.equals(names[i])) {
                System.out.println(names[i] + " is a common name.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(nameEntered + " is not a common name.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I have the else statement only print out once? If I do it like this the output it nameEntered + " it is not a common name." three times. It can't be break; right since it'll print some weird stuff when the if statement is met. If I use continue it'll check all three and the output will be like "Mary is not a common name" "Mary is a common name" "Mary is not a common name" if I input Mary

Comment: Use a logical (boolean) variable called `found`, initialize it to `false`. In the loop print nothing, only set `found` when the names match (after that you may `break`). Do every printing _after_ the loop, depending on `found`

Comment: but how would I print out a found = true statement that matches the string I input?

Comment: Just `break` when you find a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, I have edited the answer. You have to use a flag as suggested in comments. See below-

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names[] = {"John", "Mary", "Peter"};

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String nameEntered = myScanner.nextLine();

        boolean nameFound = false;
        for (String name : names){
            if (nameEntered.equals(name)) 
                nameFound = true;            
        } 
        if(nameFound)
            System.out.println(nameEntered + " is a common name.");
        else
            System.out.println(nameEntered + " is not a common name.");
    }
}
```

See the attached screenshot of the output below-

[image]

The code can be accessed by following [this link](https://onlinegdb.com/HkMDZFf9L).

Comment: this forces you to keep inputting new names right? I just want to input the name once and it checks the array.

Comment: Much simpler and neat!

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't show me any output if I enter an uncommon name

Comment: im sorry but can you explain why and what (String name : names) does? and why you cant use the typical for loop. This code works though thank you.

Comment: `for (String name : names)` is a neat/enhanced way of iterating in Java. You can definitely, replace it with traditional `for` loop, i.e., `for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)`. Note that the `for` loop in your question is out of the bounds. If you use the enhanced way, then you don't need to worry about bounds. Anyway, as you said that the code works, therefore please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use continue or break statement.

```
public class array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names[] = {"John", "Mary", "Peter"};

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String nameEntered = myScanner.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i <= names.length; i++) {
            if (nameEntered.equals(names[i])) {
                System.out.println(names[i] + " is a common name.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(nameEntered + " is not a common name.");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could avoid the loop in the first place? (Only Java 8 and above though)
I know not exactly what you were looking for but for me feels natural.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names[] = {"John", "Mary", "Peter"};

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String nameEntered = myScanner.nextLine();


        String result = Arrays.stream(names).
                                filter(nameEntered::equals).
                                findAny().
                                map(name -> name + " is a common name.").
                                orElseGet(() -> nameEntered + " is not a common name.");

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

[image: Example run]